# physics engine with multiple object groups

Tags: java, physics-engine

My java application requires a 2d physics engine for a horizontal world, however, looking at jbox2d and dyn4j, it seems that they don't offer what I need out-of-the-box. Specifically, they don't support defining which object groups can collide with others. Consider this simplified model: Bullets can collide with boxes. Planes pass through boxes, but they can collide with bullets.

**How do I exclude certain groups of objects from colliding in a physics engine?**

Comment: If you're trying to make a game I recommend Unity, this kind of thing is already implemented for you. If you want to use java and this specific engine you could define your own collides with function that only checks for the collision of objects you want

Comment: Thanks! This is a headless server and I need to stick with JVM stack. As for your suggestion, could you please elaborate? How would I prevent a plane bouncing off a box, even if I check their types in an event handler?

Comment: Friendly reminder: downvoter(s) should consider adding a comment explaining what should be improved.

Comment: This question is too broad & opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution in box2d (and jbox2d respectively).
The "PreSolve" method allows to disable a contact before colliding. See [this question on gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15985/how-can-i-cancel-a-contact-in-a-b2contactlistener) which has pretty much the same problem as described here.

From documentation:

> Pre-Solve Event
>
> This is called after collision detection, but before collision resolution. This gives you a chance to disable the contact based on the current configuration. For example, you can implement a one-sided platform using this callback and calling b2Contact::SetEnabled(false). The contact will be re-enabled each time through collision processing, so you will need to disable the contact every time-step. The pre-solve event may be fired multiple times per time step per contact due to continuous collision detection.

Comment: Please see [answer] about links. Provide a small snippet of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dyn4j has the [CategoryFilter](http://docs.dyn4j.org/v3.2.0/org/dyn4j/collision/CategoryFilter.html). You create CategoryFilters with two longs and set those in your Fixtures. It's a little funny how the filters work because the category and mask are used in their binary forms to determine who can collide with who. To see this in practice check out this [@Test](https://github.com/dyn4j/dyn4j/blob/master/src/test/java/org/dyn4j/collision/CategoryFilterTest.java) from the Dyn4j repo.
Dyn4j also mentions this in the [docs](http://www.dyn4j.org/documentation/advanced/#Collision_Filtering):

> There are three Filter implementations provided, the Filter.DEFAULT_FILTER, the CategoryFilter (just like Box2D’s collision filter, int category + mask), and the TypeFilter.

So I'm assuming Box2D has this too (and jBox2d by extension). I'd say just about any physics engine at Box2D's or Dyn4j's level will have this ability in some form.